# Error: borrowed value is only... reference must be valid for

Tags: rust

I'm getting these errors when compiling the code below (code 1)

> error: `v` does not live long enough vec.push(&v);
>
> note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement
>   0 at 15:64...
>
> note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix
>   following statement 2 at 19:35

(code 1)

```
fn main() {

    let mut vec: Vec<&Inf> = Vec::<&Inf>::new();//<-- It appears the error

    let p: Foo1  = Foo1::created(); 
    let v: Foo2  = Foo2::created();

    vec.push(&v);
    vec.push(&p);
```

but not when I move `vec`, below `p` and `v`.

(code 2)

```
fn main() {

    let p: Foo1  = Foo1::created(); 
    let v: Foo2  = Foo2::created();

    //It does not appear the error described above
    let mut vec: Vec<&Inf> = Vec::<&Inf>::new(); //<-- It does not appear the error
    vec.push(&v);
    vec.push(&p);

..//
```

(This behavior may be normal, if it is someone can I explain me.)

This is a similar case that I created so you can see the error

---

Error <kbd>[play.rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=17803e7ca1e65b43fbaa65e3916b20fe&version=stable)</kbd>

No error <kbd>[play.rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ad6e8934a3134e9899b6d7f7dcf3d840&version=stable)</kbd>

---

I read about this [ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html) and this [borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/references-and-borrowing.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is absolutely normal and natural.

Here's a simpler example:

```
{
    let x = 1;
    let mut v = Vec::new();

    v.push(&x);
}
```

This code compiles, but this doesn't:

```
{
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    let x = 1;

    v.push(&x);
}
```

This happens because the order of variables destruction is the opposite of their construction order. In the top example it goes like this:

```
x created
v created
v[0] = &x
v destroyed
x destroyed
```

But in the bottom one we have this:

```
v created
x created
v[0] = &x
x destroyed  // x is destroyed, but v still holds a reference to x!
v destroyed
```

That is, in the bottom example there is a moment (albeit close to invisible) when there is an outstanding reference to `x` which is already destroyed.